# Disable minimize button in internet explorer opened in a Citrix instance

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, citrix

I've disabled the system menu buttons in the past on many windows using GetWindowLong (or GetWindowLongPtr if 64-bit) and SetWindowLong (or SetWindowLongPtr) with great success.  I have a Citrix session that launches internet explorer and I cannot get these items to be removed from the title bar.  I know the method that I am using is working because I can do what I want to do when a normal, non-Citrix, internet explorer is open.  I successfully get the window handle for the Citrix IE session as I can focus it, set it to topmost, etc.  It just does not want to work with Get/SetWindowLong and is obviously something to do with Citrix.  Ignore the attribute parameter - I will eventually be passing in what WS_ will be used to manipulate the window, but I just want to keep it simple until I get this working (if it is even possible).

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]

 internal extern static long SetWindowLong(int hwnd, int index, long value);



[DllImport("user32.dll")]

internal extern static long GetWindowLong(int hwnd, int index);



public static void SetWindowAttribute(int hwnd, int attribute)

{

    IntPtr hwndPtr = new IntPtr(hwnd);

    const int GWL_STYLE = -16;

    const long WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x00020000L;

    const long WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x00010000L;



    long value = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);

    Trace.TraceInformation("GetWindowLong value {0}", value.ToString());

    long ret = SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, (value & ~WS_MINIMIZEBOX & ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX));

    Trace.TraceInformation("SetWindowLong reg {0}", ret.ToString());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code above is for 32-bit, then on the `SetWindowLong` declaration the `value` parameter type should be `int`, not `long`.  There is a possibility this may cause some inconsistent behavior.

For reference, here are the 32-bit signatures as defined internally in System.Windows.Forms:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong")]
public static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr32(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, HandleRef dwNewLong);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "GetWindowLong")]
public static extern IntPtr GetWindowLong32(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex);
```

Also, using Spy++, you can verify what styles are on the IE window before and after you modify the style.